# Need help compiling a custom, minimal FFmpeg build

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, music

I'm using FFmpeg's [showspectrumpic](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showspectrumpic) function to generate spectrogram pictures :
[image]

I have a working FFmpeg build that does what I need, but it's quite heavy (almost 100mo).

Is it possible to compile a FFmpeg build with the minimal requirements to run just the “showspectrumpic” function ? I have no clue how compiling works.

I've already tried the [media-autobuild_suite](https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite), but it gives me errors that I don't understand. Maybe I messed up the setup, I honestly don't know.

Either way, any info on “FFmpeg builds for noobs” is more than welcome

Thanks y'all \o